# How do i set the proxy and SOCKs in libcurl?

Tags: .net, libcurl, socks

I am trying to configure my .NET app to use a proxy. My source is in C# but i learned CURL via C++. My question is where do i put the SOCKs IP and port? i looked through [the documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) and didnt see it. I believe that is what is causing me these problems.

When i run this code it will quiet literally timeout and not call my header function or writer function. If i comment out the first two curlopt lines (the two proxy lines) my code runs with no problems.

In firefox i set the http proxy and SOCKs host separately, they are different IPs and ports. How do i set the sock part, the below has the dummy proxy set but i cant figure out the socks part.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SeasideResearch.LibCurlNet.Curl.GlobalInit((int)SeasideResearch.LibCurlNet.CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
        var curl = new Easy();
        {
            curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://127.0.0.1:1234");
            curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLproxyType.CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
            curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, "http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup");
            curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_USERAGENT, @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2b5) Gecko/20091204 Firefox/3.6b5");
            curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, hf);
            curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, data);
            curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wf);
            curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, sw);
            curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl.Perform();
            var sz = sw.ToString();
            var myrealip = sz.IndexOf("12.34.56.78") !=-1; 
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(sz);
        SeasideResearch.LibCurlNet.Curl.GlobalCleanup();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only place you can put the SOCKS proxy's address in `CURLOPT_PROXY`. You can either have an HTTP proxy or a SOCKS proxy, not both.